# Postgres. Inner join with 1 to many

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, inner-join

Need your help.
I have 3 tables

products
|  id  |  title | price | .... |

product_to_category_list
|  id  | product_id  | category_id  |

and "categories"
|  id  | cat_title |

For each product in "products" table can be connected many rows in "product_to_category_list" 'cause one product can be related to different categories in the same time.

I need a query to get All products that is associated with a few certain categories + extra column with all categories for this product separated by commas.

For ex. I need a product that associated with two categories (3 and 5) :(product_to_category_list.category_id = 3 and product_to_category_list.category_id = 5)

```
select 
"products"."id", "title", "manufacturer", "amount", "price", 
"photo", "description", "available", "valid_until", "weight",
array_to_string(array_agg(product_to_category_list.category_id), ',') as category_id


from "products" inner join "product_to_category_list" on "products"."id" = "product_to_category_list"."product_id" 
where (category_id = 5 ) and 
(select 
count("title") from "products" inner join "product_to_category_list" on "products"."id" = "product_to_category_list"."product_id" 
 where (category_id =3)  ) >0


group by "products"."id"
```

[ScreenShot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BNF8t.jpg)
It returns me Almost the result that I need But:
1) category_id contains just value 5
2) query generates dynamically and it can be 3-5 categories for one product as condition, and I'm not sure that 5 inner selects are a good idea.

---

I designed another query:

```
select p.title,p.manufacturer, p.amount,p.price,p.photo,p.description, p.available, p.valid_until,p.weight, 
array_to_string(array_agg(c.category_id), ',') as cats_id
      from products p
      INNER JOIN product_to_category_list c ON c.product_id = p.id [[[where cats_id like "%paramCat_1%" and cats_id like "%paramCat_2%" ....  ]]]]
      group by p.id
```

It returns:
[ScreenShot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OPJxz.jpg)

And again it's almost what I need, but I can't use a new alias with Where and Like condition to compare it with my categories.

So, how can I get One row with all data from products and all categories from product_to_category_list.category_id  associated with the products.id, separated by commas (in an extra field)

Hope for your help ;)

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text.Include a legend/key & explanation with an image.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input (as initialization code) with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For errors that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL, which includes constraints & indexes & tabular initialization. [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a subselect from the product_to_category_list table to get a list of the product ids you need, and join your query to that.

```
SELECT p.title,p.manufacturer, p.amount,p.price,p.photo,p.description, p.available, p.valid_until,p.weight,
array_to_string(array_agg(c.category_id), ',') AS cats_id
FROM products p
INNER JOIN product_to_category_list c 
    ON c.product_id = p.id 
INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT product_id FROM WP.product_to_category_list WHERE category_id IN (3,5) ) c_limit
    ON c_limit.product_id = p.id
GROUP BY p.title,p.manufacturer, p.amount,p.price,p.photo,p.description, p.available, p.valid_until,p.weight
```